# Getting error if bootstrap is run from server but no error if run from file

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and doing small examples by seeing the example.I have downloaded the bootstrap css files from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and I am using bootstrap 3.I am just creating a nav bar and following is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Employee Directory</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="icomoon/style.css">


</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my app name is gift

If I am accessing the file from tomcat server like `http://localhost:8080/gift/index.html` then I am getting error.Please see the screenshot

[image]

**But if right click on the index.html and open it google chrome then I am not getting any error.**
(the below image)
Please tell me why is it so?

[image]

Comment: well from your code, there isn't any mistakes, just try restructuring with standard structure where you put the `jquery` before `</body>`. And try to check each of the error by clicking on them in the browser. It may help

Comment: @rockStar so where do I need to keep the jquery?

Comment: just a wild guess,remove `http:` from the src inclusion and then add the bootstrap file => `href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks for trying to help.I did your way(removed http:) like this `<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` still the same.I have also downloaded the bootstrap.min.css and kept that in the css folder and tried this way `<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` still the same

Comment: no, i didnt say remove the `http`, you actually need it. and put the jquery code before the `</body>` tag

Comment: @rockStar If I keep jquery at bottom then I get an error in console saying `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call jquery https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js in header before calling bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am doing this. see `<script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` placed before bootstrap

Comment: try to use 1.6.1 it is working for me as some feature is depriciated in jquery1.9.1

Comment: I can not use older version because bootstrap does not support

Comment: i m using this         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="../css/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3?

Comment: yes i have downloded latest bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com  so i guess its 3.1.0

Comment: Are you running from tomcat server or just right click and opeing in the browser?

Comment: i m using iis as my website in .net

Comment: Why its not working in my system,I tried your way also

Comment: if it is working in iis  then it must work on tomcat or other servers too

Comment: try to use jquery 1.6 just for testing purpose and place all bootstrap and jquery inside  header tag

Comment: I used jquery 1.6 and it gives me error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`

Comment: on is introduced in jquery 1.7 in jquery 1.6 use bind

Comment: try to download bootstrap version 3.0.2 then use it with jquery 1.6

Comment: i did this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js "></script>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!--<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="icomoon/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: can you tell me which version of bootstrap have you downloaded

Comment: or simply try to put <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

Comment: Do you have gmail?Can we discuss in gmail?

Comment: sumitgoyal9@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent you a mail ,please check

Comment: sorry its sumitgoyal19@gmail.com